# WizardImageFile does not work in Inno Setup 5.5.8

Tags: image, installation, inno-setup, setup-project

I installed the latest version of Inno Setup v5.5.8 (a) and now I can not view the `WizardImageFile` bitmap file in my installation wizard. It worked just fine in a the previous version. Am I doing something wrong or its a bug? Here a script example I created with the help of the Inno Setup wizard it self.

Of course the `setup_inno.bmp` and `setup_inno_small.bmp` are in the same folder as the iss script file. The small image works just fine and the `setup_inno.bmp` is 24bit color depth (Windows format) with 164X314 pixels width and height.

Any recommendation?

Regards,

```
#define MyAppName "My Program"
#define MyAppVersion "1.5"

[Setup]
AppId={{EF909D9F-7C2F-46E8-9BBF-C65D3323A436}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
OutputBaseFilename=setup
WizardImageFile=setup_inno.bmp
WizardSmallImageFile=setup_inno_small.bmp
WindowStartMaximized=yes
WindowShowCaption=no
WindowVisible=yes
BackColor=$000000
BackColor2=$FFFFFF
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are you aware that the Welcome page is by default skipped since [Inno Setup 5.5.7](https://jrsoftware.org/files/is5.5-whatsnew.htm#5.5.7)?

> As recommended by Microsoft's desktop applications guideline, `DisableWelcomePage` now defaults to `yes`. ... The defaults in all previous versions were `no`.

So you can actually see the `WizardImageFile` on the last (Finished) page only, not on the first (Welcome) page already as previously.

Comment: Thanx, you are the best :-)

Answer (score 3):

I found this [answer](http://news.jrsoftware.org/read/article.php?id=105812&group=jrsoftware.innosetup#105812). It states:

> The `WizardImageFile` is shown on the **Welcome** and **Finish** pages.  However, the Welcome page is *skipped by default* now (see `DisableWelcomePage`), so it will normally only be visible on the Finished page.  (This is enabled by default, but it is possible that you disabled that too -- see `DisableFinishedPage`.)
>
> The `WizardSmallImageFile` is shown on all other pages.

That explains why I can’t see the images. Wonder by the **Welcome** Page is off by default?

I found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn742479.aspx) which states:

> **Don't use Welcome pages—make the first page functional whenever possible.** Use an optional Getting Started page only when:
>
> - The wizard has prerequisites that are necessary to complete the wizard successfully.
> - Users may not understand the purpose of the wizard based on its first Choice page, and there isn't room for further explanation.
> - The main instruction for Getting Started pages is "Before you begin:".